# Artifactory fails to start (admin credentials do not exist)

Tags: docker, artifactory

I use the docker image `docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.4.6`.

Where the container restarts, I have the following error :

`[ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: bootstrap admin credentials do not exist in the config store`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try with `:latest`?

Comment: Same error with `:latest`.

Comment: Can you post your complete run command

Comment: I run it with Kubernetes, I only add the following java options : `-Xmx2g -Djfrog.access.force.replace.existing.root.keys=true`.

Comment: Can you run it as a docker container normally and see if it works on the node where it is getting scheduled? I ran the image and it works fine for me

Comment: I have the error if I attach a volume to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data` which is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Fix owner and permission of db.properties. That should solve your problem.